# What book was Hanekawa reading while Araragi tries to find where Tsunade lives?

Tags: monogatari-series

On episode 8 of *Monogatari Series: Second Season*, when Araragi tries to find where Tsunade (Hachikuji's mother) live. He met Lolikawa - young Hanekawa, and she was reading a book

[image]

**What book is it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She was reading [*"On the Banks of Plum Creek"*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0064400042). It is a children's book written in 1937 by Laura Ingalls Wilder

[image]
[image]

The book is based on Laura's childhood at Plum Creek near Walnut Grove, Minnesota in the late nineteenth century. It describes the family's move to Minnesota, where they live in a dugout until a new house is built and face misfortunes caused by flood, blizzard, and grasshoppers.